# Use twitter api on behalf of another twitter account

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

How can i use twitter api to post tweet on behalf of another account (in my possession) ? I have a developer account on my main twitter account, i created an app and i wanted to use this app to post tweets from a different twitter account and not my main. I've been trying to understand the docs but i found them very confusing, so please dont reply with things like "check docs". Thanks in advance

I tried to find a way to construct a oauth link with scopes and things like that but i get errors, and even if i got it to work, i dont know how to use the code i get from the auth. Also how do i need to auth the requests to the api in order to post tweets from the other account?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am using Tweepy library.

**1. Try refer this python code to get the access token and access secret for your another account.**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Copyright 2017 Twitter, Inc.
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

# This script generates a user's access tokens which can be used to make requests on behalf of the user, also known as OAuth 1.0a (user context) authentication method
# Docs: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens

import sys
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

#Prompt developer to enter App credentials
print("Enter the credentials for your developer App below.")
CONSUMER_KEY = input("Consumer key: ")
CONSUMER_SECRET = input("Consumer secret: ")
ACCESS_TOKEN = input("Access token: ")
TOKEN_SECRET = input("Access token secret: ")

# Request an OAuth Request Token. This is the first step of the 3-legged OAuth flow. This generates a token that you can use to request user authorization for access.
def request_token():

    oauth = OAuth1Session(CONSUMER_KEY, client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET, callback_uri='oob')

    url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"

    try:
        response = oauth.fetch_request_token(url)
        resource_owner_oauth_token = response.get('oauth_token')
        resource_owner_oauth_token_secret = response.get('oauth_token_secret')
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(e)
            sys.exit(120)
    
    return resource_owner_oauth_token, resource_owner_oauth_token_secret

# Use the OAuth Request Token received in the previous step to redirect the user to authorize your developer App for access.
def get_user_authorization(resource_owner_oauth_token):

    authorization_url = f"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={resource_owner_oauth_token}"
    authorization_pin = input(f" \n Send the following URL to the user you want to generate access tokens for. \n → {authorization_url} \n This URL will allow the user to authorize your application and generate a PIN. \n Paste PIN here: ")

    return(authorization_pin)

# Exchange the OAuth Request Token you obtained previously for the user’s Access Tokens.
def get_user_access_tokens(resource_owner_oauth_token, resource_owner_oauth_token_secret, authorization_pin):

    oauth = OAuth1Session(CONSUMER_KEY, 
                            client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                            resource_owner_key=resource_owner_oauth_token, 
                            resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_oauth_token_secret, 
                            verifier=authorization_pin)
    
    url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"

    try: 
        response = oauth.fetch_access_token(url)
        access_token = response['oauth_token']
        access_token_secret = response['oauth_token_secret']
        user_id = response['user_id']
        screen_name = response['screen_name']
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(e)
            sys.exit(120)

    return(access_token, access_token_secret, user_id, screen_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    resource_owner_oauth_token, resource_owner_oauth_token_secret = request_token()
    authorization_pin = get_user_authorization(resource_owner_oauth_token)
    access_token, access_token_secret, user_id, screen_name = get_user_access_tokens(resource_owner_oauth_token, resource_owner_oauth_token_secret, authorization_pin)
    print(f"\n User @handle: {screen_name}", f"\n User ID: {user_id}", f"\n User access token: {access_token}", f" \n User access token secret: {access_token_secret} \n")
```

Reference : https://github.com/twitterdev/enterprise-scripts-python/blob/main/Engagement-API/generate_user_access_tokens.py

**2. Click the authorization URL**

**3. Paste the code you got from the auth to the terminal.**

> [image]

You will get this final output something like this.

```
User @handle: [YOUR_TWITTER_HANDLENAME]
User ID: [YOUR_TWITTER_USERID]
User access token: [YOUR_TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN]
User access token secret: [YOUR_TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET_TOKEN]
```

**4. Then, use that access token and secret in your python script to tweet from another account. Note that need to use the same consumer token and secret of the main to ensure it works.**

For example:

```py
    import tweepy
    
    CONSUMER_KEY = "YOUR_MAIN_ACCOUNT_CONSUMER_KEY"
    CONSUMER_SECRET = "YOUR_MAIN_ACCOUNT_CONSUMER_SECRET"

    # Comment out your main access token and secret
    # ACCESS_TOKEN = "YOUR_MAIN_TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    # ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "YOUR_MAIN_TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"
    
    # Use new token obtained from the authentication.
    ACCESS_TOKEN = "YOUR_ANOTHER_TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "YOUR_ANOTHER_TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"
    
    # Authenticate to Twitter
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    
    # Create API object
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
    # Create a tweet
    api.update_status("Hello Tweepy!")
```